# "await is only valid in async" error on Firefox webextension on pageAction.getTitle()

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

According to the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction/getTitle), **browser.pageAction.getTitle()**

> is an asynchronous function that returns a Promise.

So the way I'm trying to implement it in my code is inside of a function like so:

```
function title(t){
  if(t===undefined){
    try{
      let t=await browser.pageAction.getTitle({tabId:c.id});
    }
    catch(err){
      try{
        let t=await browser.browserAction.getTitle({tabId:c.id});
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log("Failed to get title. This add-on depends on the button's title.");
      }
    }
    return t;
  }
  else{
    try{
      browser.pageAction.setTitle({tabId:c.id,title:t});
    }
    catch(err){
      try{
        browser.browserAction.setTitle({tabId:c.id,title:t});
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log("Failed to set title. This add-on depends on the button's title.");
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("Setting button title: "+t);
}
```

Is it just my mistake or is it what would seem obvious at first glance, i.e. the documentation is wrong (not updated)?

Comment: As the error message tells you, you can only use `await` in a `async` function.

Comment: There is no `async function x() {}` or `async () => {}` in your code, so, yeah, `await` would be invalid ... `async function title(t){` will fix that up (though, remember, whatever calls it needs to expect a promise as the return value)

Comment: also, having `let t` inside the `try` blocks will mean that the returned `t` won't be anything but the `t` passed in to the function ... i.e. `undefined`

Comment: I feel ashamed now, lol. asyncs are new to me and I guess I should've read more on that. The **let**s were just leftovers I forgot to delete from before putting in the **try**, but thanks for that, too.

Comment: a quick question before you go ... why do you try `browser.pageAction.getTitle` then `browser.browserAction.getTitle` if it throws? Are they both valid, but can throw an error depending on some condition? seems odd you don't do that with the setTitle code, since if `browser.pageAction.setTitle` then `browser.browserAction.setTitle` won't ever be run

Comment: That would be, because the pageAction.getTitle() is not valid for the android version of firefox which makes me quite sad. As for the setTitle I hadn't rewritten the code yet, when I found that out, when I copied it :)

Comment: And the reason the one is not used if the other one is, is because I prefer not to change the title of the browser button if it's not used. It's a bit complicated but suits the need of the addon.

Comment: so `browser.pageAction` is not a valid property or just fails? I ask, because I can make your code very small if that's the case :p

Comment: Spits an error in the console and stops further processing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181040/discussion-between-g-g-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 1):

Just prefix your function with `async`:

```
async function title(t){
    await browser.pageAction.getTitle({tabId:c.id});
}
```